# ArcGIS 10 sample selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-statistics, sampling

I am using ArcGIS 10 and I would like to select (in a manner of well spatially distributed) some of the polygons included in a shapefile as testing population for a statistical analysis.

The rest of the polygons included in the shapefile I intend to use them for the validation of the statistical outcome. As I am not so familiar with statistics, is there a way to automatically select a well spatially distributed sample in ArcGIS or if not, can you please suggest other solutions?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I just found the command Subset Features at Geostatistical Analyst Tools-Utilities. The result seems OK, however I do not how objective it is. Do you have any experience on this?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tools that can do this.  One option though is to create a new field in the layer and generate a random numbers in it, here are the steps:

1. Create new field type Double
2. Right click on field and select Calculate Field option
3. For the field calculation type in **rnd**, and press Ok button to calculate
4. After calculation, right click field and select one of the sorted options (ascending or descending)
5. Finally, from top of table select down word number of features you want selected.

This should give you a random selection of polygon features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that your polygons are evenly distributed, you can create a [fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) then select the polygons that include your points. Note that in this case, the probability to select a polygon is proportional to its size: this might be good or bad depending on our needs.

My recommendation is to compute a random value (random.random() with Python) in the attribute field of your polygons, then sort based on this value and select the first N polygons. This method is pure random (your polygon could all be in the same region, but if you could choose how a simple random sample should look like, then its no more simple random...)